# Is it possible to use the geocoder API/search box to search for markers on a map?

Tags: javascript, angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I will be using Mapbox within an Angular app with a large number of markers on the mapbox instance (in the order of several thousands) and would like users to be able to use a search box to search among the map markers (which will have, at the very least, a unique name and a set of coordinates, often also an address). Is this possible at all?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly after that search?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with use of `filter` property. It works very well on big sets of data

[Mapbox: filter | help](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/filter/)